# Android out of memory on picture load

Tags: java, android, memory, out-of-memory, ram

I am loading images into memory in android phone so I can pass them into a web service through a webservice.

Sometimes i get out of memory error, i can already catch this exception with

```
    try{
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    }catch(OutOfMemoryError ofmE){
        System.out.println("OUT OF MEMORY $$$$$$$$" + ofmE);
    }
```

Although i need to execute this operation, so i need to clean the ram memory. How can i do this? programatically i mean.

Comment: Loading large bitmaps into memory is a classic problem. You have to scale them down: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html  Otherwise, look for a way to pass the file without decoding it.

Comment: That is true, but as small as it can be it might always give you a outofmemory exception.

Comment: the size of the file doesn't matter, it's how big it is when loaded in to memory.. you can half the size by using RGB_565 instead of ARGB_8888 (the default), for example - see the link that @NigelK posted

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It's the cleaner way.

Comment: That is too much of a overhead, just to clean ram memory. I certainly don't need to add a new library, because this is a part of a large project.

Comment: You can use `System.gc();` but with that you don't fix the problem. You need to `recycle()` the unnused bitmaps and resize the image before create the bitmap. Trust me, use Picasso, you will be happier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed the method decodeFile(String pathName, BitmapFactory.Options opts)? Use options to scale down the image size for saving memory. Refer to [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html). **public int inSampleSize    If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory**. For example, you can set `inSampleSize = 4`. To recycle bitmap, you can use bm.recycle();